# Want to change the vertical position of SVG line element

Tags: javascript

i am new with svg. I want to change the position of a line. but setAttribute() not working.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setAttributeNS()`. Example:

```
 element.setAttributeNS( null, 'x', '100' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , Now i m facing the problem that when i want to add some numeric value to previous 'y1' of line , it gives error.

Comment: For example, n.children[0].setAttributeNS(null,'y1',n.children[0].getAttribute['y1'] + 78);

Comment: You must use string values. String(n.children[0].setAttributeNS(null,'y1',n.getAttribute['y1'] + 78)

Comment: This is also not working 
n.children[0[.setAttributeNS(null,'y1',Math.round(n.children[0].getAttribute['y1])+78);

Comment: But i want to add numeric value. 
1 + 78 = 79 in case of numbers , but would be 178 in case of strings.

Comment: Element attribute type is String. You must convert it to number, add 78 and then convert it back to string.